# Why does this date formatting not work?

Tags: ios, swift

I am puzzled. I read the international spec for formats...yet it seems to return a nil in playgrounds and in code.

```
let dateString = "022018"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMyyyy")

let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

I can't change the stringDate to be 02/2018...I have to maintain that format..what is the right mask then to get some output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the call to `formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`. I don't think this means what you think it does. You are turning a *string* to a *date*, not a *date* to a *string*. Just set the formatter's `dateFormat`. This works fine (Swift 3, hope you don't mind):

```
    let dateString = "022018"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMyyyy"
    let date = formatter.date(from:dateString)
```

Comment: Because that's the correct answer, @RashwanL. Translate that to your own time zone and you will see that it is midnight on February 1, 2018, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The community deemed my efforts as insufficient so they downvoted. 
Don't know...Perhaps I should have been consulting a natural language expert - to decipher the real meaning of an ambigious method signature. Anyway, this simple problem together with the solution is worth a few credits.